# Unmarshalling String XML with JAXB not working and returning just null values

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshall a String XML to a POJO Object without success. This is the code i am using

```
MyObject myobject = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(myxmlstring), MyObject.class);
```

The Xml is structured and object is structured as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:SomePerson xmlns:ns2="http://to/something">
    <SomePerson>
        <person>
            <name>joe</name>
        </person>
    </SomePerson>
</ns2:SomePerson>
```

this is my Object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="SomePerson")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    //getter and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to do something like this ::

```
        final DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        final InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("<root><node1></node1></root>")); // put your xml string here

        final Document doc = db.parse(is);

        final XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        final DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        final XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(domSource);
        final XMLReaderWithoutNamespace xr = new XMLReaderWithoutNamespace(xsr);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext
                .newInstance("POJO LOCATION").createUnmarshaller();
        return (POJOClass) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xr);
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Please *explain* in the answer above what you believe the original poster's problems are, and how your code fixes this. A paragraph or two of text would suffice. This will make your answer more than a "code-dump" answer and can make it helpful to future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your class MyObject describes XML structure with root element named "SomePerson" containing child element "name" like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SomePerson>
    <name>joe</name>
</SomePerson>
```

And XML you're trying to parse contains additional elements "SomePerson" and "person", which are not described in your JAXB class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:SomePerson xmlns:ns2="http://to/something">
    <SomePerson> <!-- definition missing -->
        <person> <!-- definition missing -->
            <name>joe</name>
        </person>
    </SomePerson>
</ns2:SomePerson>
```

You should either fix the structure of your XML document or add missing fields to your JAXB classes definitions.